# Jroland/kafka-net Group Id assignment in Consumer

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-net

I'm trying [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) c# client libraries. 
First, I built a basic producer and consumer app in [confluent-kafka-dotnet](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet) and honestly, it covered my needs, though, I wanted to give a try to [kafka-net](https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net) library.

But I couldn't find a way to consume values by group-id like [confluent-kafka-dotnet](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet).

```
    var conf = new ConsumerConfig
    { 
        GroupId = "test-consumer-group",
        BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
        AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetResetType.Latest
    };
```

Is there any way to assign a group-id to the consumer in [kafka-net](https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net)?

Thanks.